# Accessing # of WIFI bars in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi, wear-os, wifimanager

This is the receiver that I have created. The issue is that it does not give me any new values. I feel like it does not receive anything. How can I make myself receive something, why isn't it working here? I did it the same way for battery level and it worked. Finally, when I figure out how to receive something, how am I to get the WIFI bars ( I think if I make this thing return something then the WIFI bars will make more sense).

```
final BroadcastReceiver mWifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            int state = wifi.getWifiState();
            if(state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
                List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();



                for (ScanResult result : results) {

                    if(result.BSSID.equals(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID())) {
                        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(),
                                result.level);

                        int difference = level * 100 / result.level;

                        if(difference >= 100)
                            signalStrength = 4;
                        else if(difference >= 75)
                            signalStrength = 3;
                        else if(difference >= 50)
                            signalStrength = 2;
                        else if(difference >= 25)
                            signalStrength = 1;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    boolean mRegisteredWifiReceiver = false;
```

Of course I handled the functions not seen here for registering, unregistering, and calling.

Here is how I did that:

```
  public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);

            if (visible) {
                registerReceiver();
                registerWifiReceiver();
                // registerBatteryReceiver();
                // Update time zone in case it changed while we weren't visible.
                mTime.clear(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
                mTime.setToNow();

                invalidate();
            } else {
                unregisterReceiver();
                unRegisterWifiReceiver();
                //unRegisterBatteryReceiver();
            }
        }
 private void registerWifiReceiver() {

            if (mRegisteredWifiReceiver)
                return;

            mRegisteredWifiReceiver = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION);
            WatchFaceService.this.registerReceiver(mWifiReceiver, filter);
        }

 private void unRegisterWifiReceiver() {

            if (!mRegisteredWifiReceiver)
                return;

            mRegisteredWifiReceiver = false;
            WatchFaceService.this.unregisterReceiver(mWifiReceiver);

}
```

Comment: Insert logging or use your debugger to be sure that your receiver is never called... and if it is indeed the problem : the relevant code is not your receiver but more the code to register/unregister it.

Comment: I have inserted logging and no result indeed... so what is wrong with my registration.. thanks...